# Need to increment values in js array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am building a dynamic `svg calendar bar`. In order to calculate how many divisions the bar needs (based in months) I divide the total width of the bar by the date diff in months to figure out how many pixels should be in each division.

Basic example: `There are 3 months between the two provided dates; The calendar bar is 935 pixels wide. 935/3(rounded) = 312. Each section of the calendar bar should be approx 312 pixels wide.`

Now for the problem. I am using a basic loop to run the math and push the values in to a javascript array. Which works fine. What I would like to do is increment each subsequent value in the array by adding it to the previous value.

Example: `1st value is 312, second value is 614 (312+312), and the final value is 936(312+614) or (312+312+312) however the math has to work.`

For some reason, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make it push the values in this manner.

Here is the code I am currently working with. (note that some of the variables that are being updated may be declared elsewhere in the script)

```
function divideCalendarBar(){

    var calBarWidth = 935;  
    var calBarDivisions = Math.round(calBarWidth/cb_dateDiff);
    var leftPositions = calBarDivisions;
    var leftPositionsArray = new Array();

    for (var i = 1; i < cb_dateDiff; i++) {     
        leftPositionsArray.push(leftPositions);
    };

    cb_leftPositionsArray = leftPositionsArray;
}
```

Any thoughts you fine folks might have are much appreciated!

Comment: `leftPositionsArray.push(leftPositions * i);`?

Comment: This worked as well. Ok guys, I'm gonna make sure I drink more coffee before I start posting stupid questions. Thanks for humoring me!

Answer (score 4):

> 1st value is 312, second value is 614 (312+312), and the final value is 936(312+614) or (312+312+312)

So you could say your first value is `312 x 1`, your second is `312 + 312 = 312 x 2` and your third is `312 + 312 + 312 = 312 x 3`.

Since you already have a loop with an index running from 1 to (presumably) 3:

```
for (var i = 1; i < cb_dateDiff; i++) {     
    leftPositionsArray.push(leftPositions * i);
};
```

Should work

Comment: I don't think this will work since you never get to `i === 3`, because you're using the less-than instead of less-than-or-equal

Comment: @jwags: Since we have no idea what `cb_dataDiff`s value actually is, then no.

Comment: From the OP, you can see that `cb_dateDiff` is the number of elements that should end up in the leftPositionArray.  Since `leftPositions` is defined as `Math.round(calBarWidth/cb_dateDiff);` we can see that the loop should run `cb_dateDiff` times, and since `i` starts at 1 it should be `<=`

Answer (score 2):

So I think you should be able to do the following

```
for (var i = 1; i <= cb_dateDiff; i++) {     
    leftPositionsArray.push(leftPositions * i);
};
```

Assuming `cb_dateDiff` is 3 in your example from above

Answer (score 0):

If we add the last value of array to `leftPositions` then it would be solved your problem

```
for (var i = 1; i < cb_dateDiff; i++) {    
     if(leftPositionsArray.length > 0){
         leftPositionsArray.push(leftPositions+[leftPositionsArray.length-1]); 
      }else{
           leftPositionsArray.push(leftPositions); 
      } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was originally provided by Matt Burland:

```
leftPositionsArray.push(leftPositions * i);
```

Thanks Matt and everyone else.